# Conversion de una tupla a un diccionario u objeto JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

Tengo una duda y es la siguiente, tengo estos datos traidos desde una BDD, en forma de una tupla

```
(('484944', 'Fisica', 2),)
```

para convertirlos vi y aplique esta forma:

```
cursos=[]
      for fila in datos:
            curso={'codigo': fila[0], 'nombre': fila[1], 'creditos': fila[2]}
            cursos.append(curso)

      return jsonify({'cursos': cursos, 'mensaje': "cursos listados"})
```

mi pregunta es fila no seria el par de ()? ya que hay dos pares de ()

la segunda pregunta es por que vienen desde la BDD de MYSQL los datos en forma de tupla? es esta una convencion?
tercera pregunta, hay otras maneras de pasar de tupla a diccionario/json que no sea esta?  soy principiante por eso mis preguntas

Answer (score 2):

Antes de nada, deberías limitar tus consultas a una única pregunta.

Dicho esto:
respecto a los pares de () no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres. La base de datos te está devolviendo una tupla de tuplas. Concretamente una tupla de un elemento (la "fila", por intentar buscar un símil) y una tupla de tres elementos (las "columnas")

Supongo que estás usando mysql-connector. Los datos los devuelve en esa forma porque es el funcionamiento por defecto del cursor. Si efectivamente estás usando esa librería puedes instanciar el cursor de esta manera:

```
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Y para terminar, hay inifinitas maneras de convertir a diccionario la estructura que tienes. Particularmente en este caso yo usaría list comprehension haciendo zip entre keys y values:

```
    cols = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'creditos']
    cursos = [dict(zip(cols, _)) for _ in datos]
    return json.dumps(cursos)
```